# Find Key name based on unique value from a property file

Tags: java, properties

I have a property file with following key-values. Please note that the values are also unique here.

```
ID1=SOMEIDVALUE1

ID2=SOMEIDVALUE2

ID3=SOMEIDVALUE3

ID4=SOMEIDVALUE4
```

In some case, i need to fetch the key name from the property file based on SOMEIDVALUE(value).

**Possible Solution :**

a) Create a new Propperty with reverse mappings

b) Load all data in a map (key-value) and create a new inverse map.

Please suggest if any other best solution is present for above scenario.

**Note** : I don't want to store the mappings in DB, Otherwise SQL query can solve this.

Comment: It sounds like you have some solutions already. That said, it seems like you're misusing/abusing properties-files here.

Comment: Note that there is not much difference between using a new reverse `Properties` object and using a new `Map`. A `Properties` object is an enhanced `HashTable`, and I don't think the subtle implementation differences are relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

As you have unique  combinations so the bidirectional maps may be useful.

You can look at guava [bimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap)

BiMap.inverse() returns a view where the position of the key type and value type are swapped.

```
BiMap<String, Integer> userId = HashBiMap.create();
String userForId = userId.inverse().get(id);
```